# Vectorised approach while holding certain entries constant in a calculation R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance between the first point on a graph and all other points. I can't make this work with `dplyr`. But the code seems to run when I use a `for loop`. I am wondering what the vectorised approach to solving this is.

Sample code:

```
set.seed(5)

#create data 
df <- data.frame("x" = runif(100, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(y = log(x)) %>%
  arrange(x)

#Function takes two tuples consisting of coordinate data and returns the euclidian distance between the points
euc_dist = function(a, b) {
  return(sqrt(sum(a - b) ^ 2))
}
```

I try and run this on the data frame. First an approach I didn't think would work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(dist = euc_dist(c(x[1], y[1]), 
                         c(x, y)))
```

Produces a variable, `dist` with a constant value, as opposed to a value for each row.
So I try something that I thought would work, but that is a bit more cumbersome.

```
df %>%
  mutate(dist = euc_dist(c(df$x[1], df$y[1]), 
                         c(x, y)))
```

This produces the same as the above.

What I want is the equivalent of this:

```
output <- c()           
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  out <- euc_dist(c(df$x[1], df$y[1]),
                  c(df$x[i], df$y[i]))
  output <- append(output, out)
}
```

Which works fine.

Is there a way to do this via a vectorized approach, ideally in `dplyr`?

Comment: A philosophical question: When you append your `dist` column, the values will be the distance between the first row in `x`, and each subsequent row in `y`. What is the point of the values in the `x` column?

Comment: and should your equation be `return(sqrt((a - b) ^ 2))` ? I think `sum` is causing your issues

Comment: As you might have figured out, your function returns a single scalar value because that is what `sum()` does. If you want to take the sum over a particular dimension, you could construct a matrix first (e.g. using `cbind()`), and then use `rowSums()`. Alternatively, you could construct a matrix and use `apply()` (slightly slower than the sum function). Also, when constructing the matrix, you need to be careful that you subtract the elements in the correct order. Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks for the response. I hope i am not being an idiot, but i think i need to add the two values together. I tried re-writing the function to: `euc_dist = function(a, b) {  return(sqrt(((b[1] - a[1]) ^ 2) +  ((b[2] - a[2]) ^2))) }`. That still doesn't work, giving me one value, rather than a separate value for each row. Perhaps I am being an idiot here, but my intention is to work out the distance between the first point in the `df`, defined by `(x1, y1)` and every other point, also defined by `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)...(xn, yn)`. Please let me know if i am being stupid.

Comment: ok I understand - I think you need this `function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return(sqrt( ((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2) ) )
}` as your function, then your call becomes `mutate(dist = euc_dist(x1 = df$x[1], y1 = df$x[1], x2 = x, y2 = y))`

Comment: @SymbolixAU Perfect, thanks for this. If you add this as an answer, i'd be happy to accept it. Any idea why that works, but not the other format - even when the `sum()` call is dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `euc_dist` function I would replace `sum()`, because it's summing *all* the values, rather than *by-row*

```r
euc_dist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return(sqrt( ((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2) ) )
}
```

And because you want to hold `(x1, y1)` constant, you need to be explicit when calling this function.

The complete solution is

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(5)

#create data 
df <- data.frame("x" = runif(100, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(y = log(x)) %>%
  arrange(x)


euc_dist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return(sqrt( ((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2) ) )
}


df %>%
  mutate(dist = euc_dist(x1 = df$x[1], y1 = df$x[1], x2 = x, y2 = y))

#              x           y      dist
# 1   0.01448234 -4.23482504 4.2493074
# 2   0.02272462 -3.78430650 3.7987978
# 3   0.03114826 -3.46899692 3.4835191
# 4   0.03901895 -3.24370787 3.2582826
# 5   0.05006142 -2.99450467 3.0091974
# ... etc
```

Noting that now your `dist` column has no meaning against the `x` column. So you may want to consider if `x` is actually meaningful in anyway. If not you could put the first `(x, y)` pair inside the function as constants.